# ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am working on a `Spring`, `MySQL` and `Hibernate` project which also contain one main application which looks constantly in the database it works according but after  few minute application throw exception

```
0    [Thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
Exception in thread "Thread-1" 3    [Thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1596)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1706)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at com.qait.cdl.commons.dao.impl.CDLHibernateDaoImpl.findAll(CDLHibernateDaoImpl.java:77)
    at com.qait.cdl.insertIsbn.InsertIsbnDatabaseLookup.run(InsertIsbnDatabaseLookup.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2103)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2026)
    ... 30 more
```

I searched on many link but didn't get exact/satisfactory reason and how to overcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, there is an main application which looks constantly in the database which use socket on every hit to the databases and when all the socket is used it gives `NoRouteToHostException` which send by OS to JVM. In order to reuse the socket I use below mention command 
`echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse`  and/or `echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle` which is explain [here](http://cherokee-project.com/doc/other_os_tuning.html).

Comment: What do i have to in case exception occurs in Windows environment.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying cause is a `NoRouteToHostException`, which means that the underlying OS is sending a "no route to host" TCP/IP error to the JVM. This indicates a network problem between the database server and this machine; check the systems' OS logs (such as `dmesg` on Linux) to see if a network card is having connectivity trouble. If not, there's an intermittent problem in your network routing, and you'll need to troubleshoot it with your network administrator.

Comment: I am using ubuntu, the database server and the apllication running on same machine. Please tell me why this exception some time occure within 5 min and some take 1 hour to occur

Comment: @rahul You're binding to the external IP of a network card instead of the loopback address (localhost). Check your kernel log right after you get the error and see if your network connection has gone offline.

Comment: web application all also working and i didn't get this error in tomcat though on every request there is a hit on database